# How do I hide a query parameter on jaxrs interface from swagger?

Tags: swagger

I have a query parameter on a jaxrs interface that I don't want to appear in the swagger generated documentation.  Can I exclude this parameter from the generated API documentation?

I'm using swagger-jaxrs_2.10 version 1.3.4.